# How to make label's background color transparent?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In Windows Forms (**WS13**) I need to make label's background color transparent, but if i'll made it in properties (**BackColor -> Transparent**), then it doesn't works with the progress bar:

[image]

Comment: There is no "real" transparent in WinForms. It is showing the background of its parent, which is gray. This is one of those things that just plain sucks in WinForms. There are hacks out there, but they tend to introduce flicker problems.

Comment: On a more constructive note, you can create your own progress bar control that will paint the text on top of the bar. This is considerably more work, but will do exactly what you want.